# Unix commands in Perl?

Tags: perl, unix

I'm very new to Perl, and I would like to make a program that creates a directory and moves a file into that directory using the Unix command like:

```
mkdir test
```

Which I know would make a directory called "test".  From there I would like to give more options like:

```
mv *.jpg test
```

That would move all .jpg files into my new directory.

So far I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Folder Name:";
$fileName = <STDIN>;
chomp($fileType);

$result=`mkdir $fileName`;
print"Your folder was created \n";
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Perl has it's own `mkdir` function...

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Was it intentional that you read the folder name into `$fileName` but chomped the variable `$fileType`? If not, `use strict` would have caught that error for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

print "Folder Name:";
$dirName = <STDIN>;
chomp($dirName);

mkdir($dirName) && print "Your folder was created \n";
rename $_, "$dirName/$_" for <*.jpg>;
```

You will have a better control when using built-in `perl` functions than using Unix commands. That's the point of my snippet.

Comment: Thanks @sputnick, but it gives me this:Your folder was created 
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory

Comment: A mix between your link and the top of my head ;)

Comment: @Scope, you have an old version

Comment: @sputnick u said I have an old version? is there a command i could do to upgrade? im sorry im very new to perl.

Comment: You just need to refresh the page & copy/paste again =)

Comment: @sputnick im still getting an error. 

`Global symbol "$fileName" requires explicit package name at fileMover.pl line 6. Global symbol "$dirName" requires explicit package name at fileMover.pl line 7. Global symbol "$dirName" requires explicit package name at fileMover.pl line 9. Global symbol "$dirName" requires explicit package name at fileMover.pl line 10.`

Comment: @Scope: `my $dirName = <STDIN>;`  The `my` declares a (lexical) variable.  Declaring variables, together with `use strict;`, guards against typos (it has other advantages as well).

Answer (score 1):

Most (if not all) Unix commands have a corresponding version as a function

e.g

mkdir - see [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/mkdir.html)

mv - See [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html)

Etc. either get a print out of the various manual pages (or probably have a trip down to the book shop - O'Reilly nut shell book is quite good along with others).

Answer (score 0):

In perl you can use bash commands in backticks.   However, what happens when the directory isn't created by the mkdir command?  Your program doesn't get notified of this and continues on its merry way thinking that everything is fine.

You should use built in command in perl that do the same thing.

- http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/mkdir.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html

It is much easier to trap errors with those functions and fail gracefully.  In addition, they run faster because you don't have to fork a new process for each command you run.

Answer (score 0):

Perl has some functions similar to those of the shell. You can just use

```
mkdir $filename;
```

You can use backquotes to run a shell command, but it is only usefull if the command returns anything to its standard output, which `mkdir` does not. For commands without output, use `system`:

```
0 == system "mv *.jpg $folder" or die "Cannot move: $?";
```